Can't add multiple sheets when creating aws_quicksight_analysis using terraform
Need to create more sheets in quicksight.
When I create a aws-quicksight-analysis using terraform, this shows up in the quicksight console:

I do not have the option to add more sheets. When I create it using the quicksight UI, I do have the option to add more sheets:

I don't know what I need to edit in my terraform code to include or enable this option.
This is my code:
resource "aws_quicksight_analysis" "my-test-analysis" {
  analysis_id = "my-first-analysis"
  name        = "my-first-analysis"

  definition {
    data_set_identifiers_declarations {
      data_set_arn = aws_quicksight_data_set.my-first-dataset.arn
      identifier   = "my_unique_identifier"
    }
    sheets {
      title        = "my-first-sheet"
      sheet_id     = "new-sheet-id"
      content_type = "INTERACTIVE"
    }
  }

  permissions {
    actions   = local.permissions
    principal = "my_quicksight_account"
  }
}

What needs to get added?
These are the permissions:
  analysis_permissions = [
    "quicksight:RestoreAnalysis",
    "quicksight:UpdateAnalysisPermissions",
    "quicksight:DeleteAnalysis",
    "quicksight:QueryAnalysis",
    "quicksight:DescribeAnalysisPermissions",
    "quicksight:DescribeAnalysis",
    "quicksight:UpdateAnalysis"
  ]


The documentation says sheets is a list rather than an object (though in their sample code they show an object).  Have you tried replacing sheets {title ...} with sheets [{title ...}, {title = "sheet 2" ...}]?

This doesn't work in terraform

Could this be related to permissions ? ... can you add fill code local.permissions and the aws_quicksight_data_set.my-first-dataset

Changed the perissions

my strategy for troubleshooting something like this is to manually create the resource (you confirmed that works correctly) then do a terraform -generate-config-out see how is the code different from what you got

@HelderSepulveda do you have any documentation on how this works? How do I connect to my AWS Resource or which I want to see the source code?

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import/generating-configuration

Hi @HelderSepulveda it worked like this! I needed to add the standard configuration for sheets to make it work. Thanks

You might want to update the question with your findings

The thing is that the json definition you export from Quicksight is not 100% compatible with Terraform. But it's possible to add a second sheet as a new sheet object, something like this:
resource "aws_quicksight_analysis" "my-test-analysis" {
  analysis_id = "my-first-analysis"
  name        = "my-first-analysis"

  definition {
    data_set_identifiers_declarations {
      data_set_arn = aws_quicksight_data_set.my-first-dataset.arn
      identifier   = "my_unique_identifier"
    }

    sheets {
      title        = "my-first-sheet"
      sheet_id     = "new-sheet-id"
      content_type = "INTERACTIVE"
    }

    sheet {
      title        = "my-second-sheet"
      sheet        = "second-sheet-id"
      content_type = "INTERACTIVE"
    }

  }

  permissions {
    actions {
      actions = [
      "quicksight:RestoreAnalysis",
      "quicksight:UpdateAnalysisPermissions",
      "quicksight:DeleteAnalysis",
      "quicksight:QueryAnalysis",
      "quicksight:DescribeAnalysisPermissions",
      "quicksight:DescribeAnalysis",
      "quicksight:UpdateAnalysis"
      ]
    principal = "my_quicksight_account"
  }
}

